# How to retrieve the dpi of the current device?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

Is there any functions to retrieve the DPI (or the screen density) of the mobile device (android/ios)? I m under Delphi Sydney.

Comment: @MahdiYusefi No, it isn't a duplicate. The question you mention use Andoid API but the OP question is related to Delphi, FireMonkey and IOS as well which offers a one line solution (see my answer). You should better read the question and pay attention to tags. Remove your comment. I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 5):

In FireMonkey various platform information is accessible through platform services. For retrieving PPI (DPI) and device display scale you can use `IFMXDeviceMetricsService` or `IFMXScreenService`

```
var
  MetricsService: IFMXDeviceMetricsService;
  Metrics: TDeviceDisplayMetrics;
  PPI: Integer;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXDeviceMetricsService, MetricsService) then
  begin
    Metrics := MetricsService.GetDisplayMetrics;
    PPI := Metrics.PixelsPerInch;
  end;
end;


var
  ScrService: IFMXScreenService;
  ScrScale: Single;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService, ScrService) then
  begin
    ScrScale := ScrService.GetScreenScale;
  end;
end;
```

List of all FMX Platform services and information you can find at [FireMonkey Platform Services](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Services)

Note: Some services, like `IFMXDeviceMetricsService`, are not listed in documentation.